# Laravel Valet - deprecated dependencies in lock file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, illuminate-container, valet

On running `composer global require laravel/valet`, illuminate/contracts and illuminate/container are locked to v5.4.36:

```
  - Locking illuminate/container (v5.4.36)
  - Locking illuminate/contracts (v5.4.36)
```

Running any `valet` command returns a long list of deprecated methods similar to the following:

```
Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/lluismather/.composer/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 1159
```

```
Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /Users/lluismather/.composer/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php on line 788
```

If I try to upgrade these I get the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires illuminate/contracts 8.77.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[v8.77.1].
    - illuminate/contracts v8.77.1 requires psr/container ^1.0 -> found psr/container[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2] but the package is fixed to 2.0.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - illuminate/container v5.4.36 requires illuminate/contracts 5.4.* -> found illuminate/contracts[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (8.77.1).
    - laravel/valet v2.18.1 requires illuminate/container ~5.1|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.4.36].
    - laravel/valet is locked to version v2.18.1 and an update of this package was not requested.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

It seems to me as though valet is locking deprecated versions of these packages, resulting in the warnings and errors I'm getting. Any thoughts or insights in how to upgrade `illuminate/contracts` and `illuminate/container` to stop the deprecation notices and make valet play ball with my current setup would be greatly appreciated.

Versions:
php 8.1.1
composer 2.1.14
laravel 8
valet 2.18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems that when a package defines its own dependencies and lists multiple major version options, the lowest one is used by default (and locked) which causes Valet to use `illuminate/container:^5.4` which drags along its own dependencies.

The solution for me was to add v8 to the global composer.json, e.g.:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/container": "^8.0",
        "laravel/installer": "^4.0",
        "laravel/valet": "^2.0",
    }
}
```

I removed the `composer.lock` file and the vendor folder and ran another `composer global update` which fixed the problem.

What is strange though, is that it only appeared recently even though I have been using PHP 8.x for quite some time.

Comment: Thanks mniess, appreciate your help here - solved it for me.